# Orchard won't let me install modules / activate features (like Vandelay Industries, etc.) anymore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, recipe

I've been running a website using Orchard 1.8.0 for some time now and I remember at some point early in development installing the Vandelay.Meta module to add meta tags/descriptions to my content pages. By pure accident I stumbled upon the fact that the website does not include any meta information on the pages anymore. I logged into the backend to find that the input fields on the content page edit have gone missing. The module was still listed in the module tab, and I tried deactivating and reactivating the feature, but it didn't help.

I logged onto the server and used the console orchard package remove command to delete the vandelay.meta folder in the module folder. The module was now gone from the module tab in the backend (as expected).

I tried reinstalling the module from the gallery, and while it claimed the installation was a success and prompted me to active the feature, it would then not show up in the modules tab, and of course also not on the content page edit site.

I tried to install some other modules like Vandelay.Industries or VXSolutions.Orchard.MetaTags, and I tried installing from the Gallery or from my computer. The result is always the same: The backend first claims that installation was successful, asks me to select the features to activate, and nothing is actually installed.

I checked Orchard's error logs, and here is what I found - but I must admit that this is on a level I have not yet worked on (I usually do frontend stuff, create themes, do some minor razor coding, etc.)

```
2015-06-25 16:50:16,823 [56] Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeHarvester - Default - Could not discover recipes because module 'VXSolutions.Orchard.MetaTags' was not found.
http://www.example.com/web/Packaging/PackagingServices/InstallLocally?redirectUrl=%2Fweb%2FAdmin%2FModules%3FpageSize%3D0

2015-06-25 16:51:26,024 [34] Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeHarvester - Default - Could not discover recipes because module 'VXSolutions.Orchard.MetaTags' was not found.
http://www.example.com/web/Packaging/PackagingServices/InstallPackageDetails?redirectUrl=%2Fweb%2FAdmin%2FModules%3FpageSize%3D0

2015-06-25 16:51:26,362 [34] Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepExecutor - Default - Recipe execution 2bf13fda53374162aa942942b24cbbd7 was cancelled because a step failed to execute
http://www.example.com/web/Packaging/PackagingServices/InstallPackageDetails?redirectUrl=%2Fweb%2FAdmin%2FModules%3FpageSize%3D0
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not enable feature VXSolutions.Orchard.MetaTags because it was not found.
at Orchard.Recipes.RecipeHandlers.FeatureRecipeHandler.ExecuteRecipeStep(RecipeContext recipeContext)
at Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepExecutor.ExecuteNextStep(String executionId)

2015-06-25 16:51:26,587 [34] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - Default - An unexpected exception was caught
http://www.example.com/web/Packaging/PackagingServices/InstallPackageDetails?redirectUrl=%2Fweb%2FAdmin%2FModules%3FpageSize%3D0
Orchard.OrchardCoreException: Recipe execution with id 2bf13fda53374162aa942942b24cbbd7 was cancelled because the "Feature" step failed to execute. The following exception was thrown: Could not enable feature VXSolutions.Orchard.MetaTags because it was not found.. Refer to the error logs for more information.
at Orchard.Recipes.Services.RecipeStepExecutor.ExecuteNextStep(String executionId)
at Orchard.Recipes.Services.R)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

Can anyone help me find the source of the problem?

Comment: It can't find your module "VXSolutions.Orchard.MetaTags". This often happens when there are compile errors. This often happens with a version mismatch, for example the target .Net framework

Comment: @devqon thank you very much for your answer, could you maybe elaborate a bit on it? As I wrote I usually don't do much "backend" stuff. If there were compile errors, shouldn't they show up somewhere in the logfiles?

Comment: If you have visual studio installed, open up the solution and try to compile the modules that aren't found manually